# How can I remove the white space from an image view with a circle shape?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to remove whitespace from both the left and right of a circular image I have in android studio. The bottom has the following image of the view:

[image: imageOne]

I will put in the code too

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        app:cardCornerRadius="75dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I've looked online and I've tried to put wrap_content on my layout_width on my ImageView tag, and it works! It takes off the white space, but leaves it as an oval instead of a circle, plus when I upload the picture, it shows up like the image below..

[image: imageTwo]

Anything yall can suggest?

Comment: It seems a confusing question as you're asking to remove white space from left & right side, and in `imageTwo` you're saying it worked but shape is changed as we can see it still has white space in ImageTwo though it is oval shape. So would be great if you ask clear question, what exactly you're expecting.
Secondly the image seems Rectangular so if we tried to put it circle shape we will loose some of image content from top and bottom which I think acceptable for you, right?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, I actually fixed it by using this website. Hope this website helps you as it helped me. Happy coding! https://www.skcript.com/svr/how-to-make-a-circular-image-view-in-android-without-third-party-library/